# Crystal get raised Exception's class

Tags: crystal-lang

I was expecting that `typeof(...)` would give me the exact class, but when rescuing an Exception `typeof(MyCustomException)` just returns `Exception`

```
class A < Exception; end
class B < A; end

begin
  raise B.new
rescue e
  puts typeof(e) # => Exception
end
```

Whereas `puts typeof(B.new)` returns B as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://github.com/bararchy on the issue I created here: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4597

```
I think that typeof is indeed Exception, but .class will give you what you want , I could be mistaken but I think that is intended
```

So yeah `e.class` returns B

Answer (score 1):

`rescue e` does not restrict the type of exception handled by this rescue block. Therefor `e` can be any exception type.

If you only want to handle exceptions of type `B`, you should add a type restriction `rescue e : B`. Then, `typeof(e)` will be `B`.